# An Open Source or paid tool to generate mock data for unit testing, performance testing and mocking production data

Tags: java, data, unit-tests, mocks

I am looking for a data generation tool that can generate large amounts of data with following requirements.

- Ability to configure type of data that needs to be generated -- Data has lot of constraints and not sample or common random data. Tool has ability to connect to Postgres or AWS.
- It is better if it can be run on AWS and the data generated can be stored in S3.
- The tool should have foreign key support so that it will generate same data for key columns of two different data sets.
- Tool should have an option to add/ remove code to meet these requirements and any more that will show up in future.
- Additional functionalities like sending alerts from tool and any option to use the tool from API's

I looked into many online open source tools like mockaroo, faker etc they are more generic and did not meet our requirements. Other database specific tools like ApexSQL which are not compatible with AWS and does not have option to code.

I also checked FINRAOS DataGenerator for big data. It has some of the above functionalities but not all of them. Could anyone help me find a tool that meets our requirements.